# MySQL Master-Slave-Slave Configuration -error 1236

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

I currently have a Master (5.5) - Slave (5.6) set up right now and I would like to add another slave that will replicate from the existing slave.

On the existing slave:

```
1. STOP SLAVE;
2. SHOW SLAVE STATUS;
3. Note these values Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.018098 & Read_Master_Log_Pos: 185753950
4. FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
5. Service mysql stop
4. Took snapshot of mysql data vol and restore it on new mysql slave server, also I changed the server-id in my.cnf on the new mysql slave.
5. service mysql start.
6. UNLOCK TABLES;
```

on the new mysql slave server (should replicate from the existing slave):

```
1. changed server-id on my.cnf
2. remove /mnt/data/mysql/auto.cnf
3. service mysql start --skip-slave-start

4.
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='existing slave',
MASTER_USER='xxx',
MASTER_PASSWORD='xxx',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.018098',
MASTER_LOG_POS=185753950;

5. execute start slave

got an error:
2016-11-18 16:39:50 5736 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Could not find first log file name in binary log index file (server_errno=1236)
2016-11-18 16:39:50 5736 [ERROR] Slave I/O: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file', Error_code: 1236
2016-11-18 16:39:50 5736 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'mysql-bin.018098', position 185753950
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replicate from the existing 5.6 slave to another 5.6 slave, you need to setup the first 5.6 slave to behave like a master

## STEP 01

Add these three(3) lines to my.cnf (under `[mysqld]` group header) on the first 5.6 slave

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=mysql-bin
log-slave-updates
skip-slave-start
```

## STEP 02

Restart mysql on the first 5.6 slave

```
service mysql restart
```

Now, the first 5.6 slave has its own binary logs

## STEP 03

Reset Binary Logs on the first 5.6 slave

```
mysql> RESET MASTER;
```

## STEP 04

On the second 5.6 Slave, setup replication to the first 5.6 slave as follows:

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='existing slave',
MASTER_USER='xxx',
MASTER_PASSWORD='xxx',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001',
MASTER_LOG_POS=4;
START SLAVE;
```

## STEP 5

Start replication on the first 5.6 slave

```
mysql> START SLAVE;
```

## STEP 6

Verify that Replication is running on both 5.6 Slaves

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

If you see `Slave_IO_Running: Yes`, `Slave_SQL_Running: Yes`, and `Seconds_Behind_Master` is a number (preferably 0), CONGRATULATIONS !!!

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49298/discussion-on-answer-by-rolandomysqldba-mysql-master-slave-slave-configuration).